# Is "For why" improper English?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, american-english

I use the phrase "For why" quite often and my friends laugh at me for it.

For example, I asked my friend about why he was going and I had asked him "for why are you going?"

Is this an incorrect use? And if so why?

Comment: Give an example of when you would use "For why?"

Comment: I asked my friend about why he was going and i had asked him "for why are you going"

Comment: Yes, that's not a native usage. You're mingling "For what?" and "Why?" *Why* functions all by itself. "What are you going for?" is equivalent to "Why are you going?"

Comment: 'For why' can be idiomatic in certain contexts, but it sounds rather old-fashioned. Googling 'for why' (in quotes) I discovered that there was a single word 'forwhy' in Middle English.

Comment: @KateBunting: What contexts would those be? I can't think of any.

Comment: Apologies to Laurel, et al, and I deliberately use "for why" from time to time, specifically in order to sound archaic, because that creates emphasis. 

Whether I do or you can get away with it is about the context, not any rules.

Comment: @Robusto If a clause headed by _why_ is the object of _for_, it can be idiomatic (though generally it feels more natural to me to leave out the preposition even there), e.g., [“dispiriting evidence for why people fall for stupid fake images online”](http://www.niemanlab.org/2018/10/a-new-study-provides-some-dispiriting-evidence-for-why-people-fall-for-stupid-fake-images-online/) – but that is of course a very different situation from the one this question is about, since _for_ here collocates with the preceding noun/verb/whatever.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I realize that it is possible to put virtually any two words together, but the OP's context is what matters here. I really wouldn't ever call that usage to be "idiomatic."

Comment: Apparently, it's influenced by your native tongue. You mean *What for*, not *For why*.

Comment: @Robusto The aforementioned Google search brings up an example, labelled 'informal' - "You're going to, and I'll tell you for why."

Comment: Another archaic usage was "What for...?" *"What for you hit my dog?"*

Answer (score 3):

The two expressions that are idiomatic in this context are "why" or "for what reason", with the former being the preferred option.

"For why" (also hyphenated or written as one word) meaning "why" as a direct interrogative was used in Old and Middle English (see the [MED](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED17343/track?counter=1&search_id=211434)'s entry), but it became obsolete sometime around the year 1500. Other senses of the expression (for example, it was used as a conjunction meaning "because") gradually over time all dropped out of use, so the word is completely obsolete and is marked as such by the OED.

At this point "for why" isn't even used in contexts where people are trying to sound archaic.

Answer (score 1):

For why' can be idiomatic in certain contexts, but it sounds rather old-fashioned. Googling 'for why' (in quotes) I discovered that there was a single word 'forwhy' in Middle English. –
Kate Bunting

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forwhy) has an entry

> #### forwhy
>
> 1. chiefly dialectal
>    : WHY, WHEREFORE
>
> #### forwhy
>
> 2. archaic
>    : BECAUSE, FOR, SINCE

#### etymology

> **Adverb**
> Middle English, from Old English for *hwī*, *for hwȳ*, […] instrumental of hwæt what
>
> **Conjunction**
> Middle English, from *forwhy*, adverb

Comment: Upvote Laurel's answer which said all of the above six years ago.

Comment: I don't agree with her last sentence, which conflicts with your first. I wouldn't have promoted a mere repeat.